# how to register firebase-messaging-sw.js using spring boot

Tags: javascript, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to develop push notification server from springboot to web browser

I have a problem when I try to register my 'sw.js' to serviceWorker

```
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey(<vapid key>)
    Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
       if(permission === 'granted'){
            console.log('Notification permission granted');
            if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
                console.log('Time to register sw.js');
                const registration = navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notifiy');
        }
    })
```

I checked 'Time to register sw.js' has been logged, but 404 error was occured.

1. 'A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script'
2. 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/') with script ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script'

firebase-messaging-sw.js is located under the resource directory, but Intellij can not find declaration about '/firebase-messaging-sw.js'.
Is this normal?

Comment: Add answer on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

try 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file move to resource/static directory.
In my case, 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file located in resource/static directory. but Spring Security had not allow access to the file. so, added 'ant.Matchers("/firebase-messaging-sw.js").permitAll()'